# Is the variable defined by a let mutable in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, let

In, for example this `let` in Common Lisp

```
(let ((a 5)) (print a))
```

Is `a` mutable as with `defparameter`, or is `a` constant as is the case with `defvar`?

Comment: Constants are created with `DEFCONSTANT`, not `DEFVAR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change what `a` is bound to, i.e. make `a` refer to something else:

```
(let ((a 5)) (setf a 10))
```

If the value referenced by `a` is mutable, you can mutate it:

```
(let ((a (list 5))) (setf (first a) 10))
```

> Is a mutable as with defparameter, or is a constant as is the case with defvar?

No, [`DEFVAR`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) does not define constants.

```
(defvar *var* :value)
(setf *var* 5)
```

Then:

```
*var*
=> 5
```

What happens is that when you evaluate a `DEFVAR` form, it first checks whether the symbol is already bound. If this is the case, then the existing value is kept in place. On the other hand, `DEFPARAMETER` always reintializes the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some examples that might clarify this. You can try them at the repl. Try to think about whether they are more like `defvar` or `defparameter`

```
(loop repeat 2 do
  (let ((a 1)) (print a) (setf a 5) (print a)))

(loop repeat 2 do
  (let ((a (list 1 2)))
    (print (first a))
    (setf (first a) 5)
    (print (first a))))

(loop repeat 2 do
  (let ((a '(1 2)))
    (print (first a))
    (setf (first a) (+ (first a) 5))
    (print (first a))))
```

Hopefully these examples should help you get a better idea of what `let` does. What happens when you put the third example into the repl is actually implementation dependant and has little to do with `let` and much more to do with `quote`.